# Bootstrap 4 ordering of jumbotron columns - order-xs- not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 jumbotron with two columns like so, and i want the second column to appear first in small screens. This is my code. But it does not work. What am I doing wrong

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 order-xs-2">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <p class="lead">This is my site</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'login' %}" role="button">Login &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 order-xs-1">
                This should be the first column on small screens
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the [migration section in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#global-changes). **The `-xs` infix is no longer used in Bootstrap 4**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 order-2 order-md-1">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <p class="lead">This is my site</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'login' %}" role="button">Login &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 order-1">
                This should be the first column on small screens
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/i1j1KHnKQp